# Classifying homomorphisms on polynomial rings with real coefficients.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism, polynomial-rings

Show that every homomorphism $\mathbb{R}$[X] $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$[X] can is equal to $φ_g$ for a unique g $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$[X], given by $φ_g(f)$ = $f(g(X))$

My guess for any homomorphism $h$, $g = h(X)$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your guess is right! Now you can directly calculate $h(f) = \varphi_g(f)$ for any $f$ explicitly, using that $h$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Every homomorphism of $\mathbb R$-*algebras*, that is, fixing $\mathbb R$.